# Merge dataframes keeping all rows from dataset A

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I am trying to merge two datasets (A and B) according to values in dataset A. Ideally, the resulting the dataset should include ALL elements from dataset A and only matching resulsts from dataset B. Dataset A contains duplicates (i.e., multiple instances of the same word). Using left_join or merge, duplicates do not get the corresponding value from dataset B (just NAs). In order to circumvent this problem, I used the code below:

```
word <- c('cat', 'house', 'cat', 'dog')
words <- as.data.frame(word)

freq <- runif(5)
sub <- as.data.frame(freq)
sub$word <- c('house', 'bottle', 'cat', 'chair', 'dog')


for(i in 1:length(words$word)){
  if (words$word[i] %in% sub$word) {
    words$freq[i] <- sub$freq[sub$word == words$word[i]]
  }
}
```

Yet, if I do this, I get a long series of warning messages ("number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"), although the output looks totally fine to me.

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `merge`:

```r
word <- c('cat', 'house', 'cat', 'dog')
words <- data.frame(word)

set.seed(42)

freq <- runif(5)
sub <- data.frame(freq)
sub$word <- c('house', 'bottle', 'cat', 'chair', 'dog')

merge(words, sub, by = "word", all.x = TRUE)
#>    word      freq
#> 1   cat 0.2861395
#> 2   cat 0.2861395
#> 3   dog 0.6417455
#> 4 house 0.9148060
```

Comment: If I use this solution, the number of rows in the resulting dataset (6517) does not match the number of row in dataset A (5459). However, it is not clear to me why I get multiple combinations.

Comment: Hm. That could happen if there are multiple matches, e.g. if you have duplicated "word"s in your sub data.frame, e.g. if `sub$word <- c('house', 'bottle', 'cat', 'chair', 'dog', 'cat')` then each cat in words gets two matches from sub and you get two additional rows.